# How to make left join criteria api in spring with ManyToOne?

Tags: java, spring, criteria, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have two simple classes with many to one relationship

```
public class User {

  Long id; 
  String name;
  ...
  (getters, setters, methods)

}

public class Item {

  Long id; 
  String name;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = PERSIST, fetch = LAZY, optional = false)
  User user;
  ...
  (getters, setters, methods)

}
```

I want to make a left join. I have tried :

```
Subquery<Long> subquery = query.subquery(Long.class)
Root<User> root = subquery.from(User .class);
Join<User, Item> join = root.join("user", JoinType.LEFT);
```

but it trow exception that there is no "user" in User, and I understand why.
How to make this right?

Comment: Your join should be inverted, because your root is User. So you are actually looking for user in User object. eg Join<Item, User>. I've also added a full example in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have something like

```
Join<Item, User> userJoin = root.join(Item_.user, JoinType.LEFT);
```

and afterwards you can use `userJoin.get(...)` with your `criteriaBuilder`

Full example with Specifications:

```
public static Specification<Item> methodName() {
   return new Specification<Item>() {
      @Override
      public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Item> root, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
         Join<Item, User> userJoin = root.join(Item_.user, JoinType.LEFT);

         return criteriaBuilder.isTrue(
            criteriaBuilder.and(
               criteriaBuilder.equal(userJoin.get(User_.id), 1),
               criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Item_.name), userJoin.get(User_.name))
            )
         );
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try joining on a column that is part of your root.
Either

```
Root<User> userRoot = ...
userRoot.join("items", JoinType.RIGHT);
```

or

```
Root<Item> itemRoot = ...
itemRoot.join("user", JoinType.LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me and produce working sql for finding User entries with matching values on User and Items.

```
CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);

Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);
Root<Item> item = cq.from(Item.class);

cq.distinct(true);

Join<Item, User> itemJoin = item.join(Item_.user);
itemJoin.on( cb.equal( root.get(User_.id), itemJoin.get(User_.id) );

predicates.add( <root predicate> );
predicates.add( <item predicate> );

[ ... ]
```